# Dynamically Choosing Elememt Types with Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

In watir we have the ability to find elements by text such as `browser.div(text:'some text')`.

In my project there are a lot of common elements like a menu dropdown that contains divs with text and class "items". In this case I could do `browser.div(text:'some text', class: 'items')` if I wanted a more generic way to access those elements.

I have this same thing with other html elements like links, spans, buttons etc. There are instances where the same text is in multiple places but just different element types. Is there anyway I could do a method where I pass the element type and still find by text?

Something like

```
def get_element_by_text(tag, text)
browser.tag(text:'some text')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, write the following method

```
browser.element(tag_name: tag,text:'some text')
```

In my above code `tag` is the variable which would receive any tag name via your formal argument of the method.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rajagopalan's answer, if you also want to differentiate between finding an array of elements or a single element, you can always user Ruby's `send()` function:
https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send

```
tag = 'input'
browser.send(tag, text: 'some text')
# browser.input(text: 'some text')
tag = 'inputs'
browser.send(tag, text: 'some text')
# browser.inputs(text: 'some text')
```

So in your case:

```
def get_element_by_text(tag, text)
  browser.send(tag, text: text)
end
```

Or make it even more dynamic

```
def get_element(tag, *args)
  browser.send(tag, args)
end
```

**Note:** Personally I'm against these kind of one-funtion-to-rule-them-all kind of behaviour. Standard Watir is in a good balance of code. When doing this, before you know it you're re-writing watir.